# upload to Azure storage from directly from Angular app

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, azure-blob-storage

I am using angular 5 and the Azure storage emulator.

I am trying to upload to Azure storage directly from my Angular app. My first step to achieve this was following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@stuarttottle/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-angular-7977e979496a). Everything works while simply uploading a single image. But when I try and upload multiple images (simply wrapping the upload functionality in a loop). Only the first is uploaded and sometimes the third. There are never more than two uploaded successfully and it is never uploads consecutive images.

to see the issue you can clone [this repo](https://github.com/stottle-uk/stottle-angular-blob-storage-upload) and change the file input to allow multiple and in `AppComponent` wrap `this.blob
      .uploadToBlobStorage(accessToken, event.target.files[0]);`
 in a loop.

I have tried calling the upload functionality as part of a web worker but no files uploaded.

Can anyone advise what the problem may be and what other things I could try to do to resolve my issue?

#

EDIT

#

It seems callbacks are the answer to my problem to some degree, but I feel I'm doing something wrong because my code looks a bit weird(to me) and I can upload all images but it's not 100% consistent. The times it fails (which is over 50% of the time) I get

> PUT http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/mySite/IMG_0593.jpg?mytoken&api-version=2017-07-29 500 (Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.)

**my code**

```
export class Photo implements IPhoto {
    image: File;
    imagePreview: string;
    thumb_image: File;
    thumb_imagePreview: string;
}

imageUrls(roomImages: Photo[]): void {

    const accessToken: IBlobAccessToken = {
        sasToken: 'myToken',
        blobAccountUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/',
        containerName: 'mySite'
    };

    for(var index = 0; index < roomImages.length; index ++)
    {
        this._blob.uploadToBlobStorage(accessToken, roomImages[index].image);
    }
}
```

**my code after edit**

```
imageUrls(roomImages: Photo[]): void {

    const accessToken: IBlobAccessToken = {
        sasToken: 'myToken',
        blobAccountUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/',
        containerName: 'mySite'
    };
    var blob = this._blob;

    for(var index = 0; index < roomImages.length; index ++)
    {
        this.blockingFunction(function() { //called to allow images to be uploaded synchronsly
            blob.uploadToBlobStorage(accessToken, roomImages[index].image);
        });  
    }
}

blockingFunction(_callback){
    _callback();    
}
```

**code from the tutorial**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

declare var AzureStorage: any;

export interface IBlobAccessToken {
  blobAccountUrl: string;
  sasToken: string;
  containerName: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class BlobStorageService {

  private finishedOrError = false;

  uploadToBlobStorage(accessToken: IBlobAccessToken, file: File): Observable<number> {
    const progress$ = new Subject<number>();
    const speedSummary = this.uploadFile(accessToken, file, progress$);

    this.refreshProgress(speedSummary, progress$);

    return progress$.asObservable();
  }

  private uploadFile(accessToken: IBlobAccessToken, file: File, progress$: Subject<number>): any {
    const customBlockSize = file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 32 ? 1024 * 1024 * 4 : 1024 * 512;
    const blobUri = accessToken.blobAccountUrl;
    const blobService = AzureStorage
      .createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, accessToken.sasToken)
      .withFilter(new AzureStorage.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());


    blobService.singleBlobPutThresholdInBytes = customBlockSize;

    return blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile(
      accessToken.containerName,
      file.name,
      file,
      { blockSize: customBlockSize },
      this.callback(progress$, accessToken)
    );
  }

  private refreshProgress(speedSummary: any, progress$: Subject<number>): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!this.finishedOrError) {
        const progress = speedSummary.getCompletePercent();
        progress$.next(progress);
        this.refreshProgress(speedSummary, progress$);
      }
    }, 200);
  }

  private callback(progress$: Subject<number>, accessToken: IBlobAccessToken): (error, result, response) => void {
    return (error, result, response) => {
      this.finishedOrError = true;
      if (error) {
        progress$.error('Error uploading to blob storage: ' + JSON.stringify(accessToken));
      } else {
        progress$.next(100);
        progress$.complete();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Tony, I just raised the issue with our internal team for other suggestions and solutions to your issue. I'll get back to you as soon as I get an update.

Comment: Thanks, I read somewhere this could be caused by me using the storage emulator and it doesn't happen in a "real" environment as often. As a work around I have written a retry (up to 3 times) for when it fails. As a result about 90% of the uploads are now successful during on of the retries. I will look forward hearing a better solution :D

Comment: You're right Tony ,It's caused by the Emulator, got the info from the internal team. I'll also update the answer above.

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest storage emulator version, enable storage logging following the below procedure, and repro this issue? The logs may help debug what is going wrong. First, turn on emulator logging by editing this file, replacing "5.7" with the current installed version:
 %LOCALAPPDATA%\AzureStorageemulator\AzureStorageEmulator.5.7.config
Set logging to true:
 <LoggingEnabled>true</LoggingEnabled>

Then restart the emulator and repro the issue. Zip up and send the log files in the following directory:
 %LOCALAPPDATA%\AzureStorageEmulator\Logs

Comment: I will do this once I get back from holiday

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly experienced when using the **Storage Emulator**. I confirmed with the internal team. Using an actual storage account would not result in the same behavior.

Comment: Is there any plans on resolving this issue?

Comment: I'm following up on this internally, will get you an update as soon  as i get any feedback